# Delete items in intermediate table for ManyToManyField without explicit through table

Tags: django

I have a `ManyToManyField` in Django that isn't using the `through` argument:

```
class Person(models.Model)
   name = models.CharField()

class Article(models.Model)
   name = models.CharField()
   person = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

I've got one article instance by article id. How can I delete the items in the intermediate table with this article id?

Comment: Can you try method 'remove'? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the related manager's [`clear()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear):

```
article.person.clear()
```

Note that this only deletes the association (i.e. the rows in the intermediate table), it will not delete anything in the `Person` table.

Comment: Document says that clear() method is only available for ForeignKey where null=True . So I should remove(). right?

Comment: @user1179442: No, it's saying that *if* you have a `ForeignKey` *then* it must be nullable. `ManyToManyFields` have the `clear()` method, you can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0c7633178fa9410f102e4708cef979b873bccb76/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L990).